# Evil force in basement possesses people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is prolly gonna be incredibly vague, so I apologize.

When I was a kid, I remember watching a movie that involved a bunch of friends in a building of some sort, and some how, they'd each inevitably end up going downstairs and opening a small door. Each time that they'd open the door, some sort of bull/demon skull would come flying toward them, and then they'd become part of the horde of other possessed individuals.

Eventually it got down to a much smaller number (I believe it was just a guy and a gal that ended up surviving), and they had to make it up and over a wall before sunrise to escape with their lives.

I've been thinking about this movie off and on for the past decade, so if anybody could provide some closure, I'd be very greatly obliged.

Comment: Was it a motion picture or a TV show? (It sounds like an episode of Tales From The Crypt or something.)

Comment: I want to say that it was a motion picture, but as my attention span was worse then than it is now, it could very well have been one of those shows.

Comment: how long ago were you "a kid" - and did it seem like an old or recent movie at the time?

Comment: Ah yes,I suppose that'd be some relevant info. It was about... Two decades ago at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this may be [Night of the Demons](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093624/) - the original 1988 version.

According to [the wikipedia synopsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Demons_%281988_film%29), the movie takes place in an old mortuary which had been converted into a house. After a power outage, people begin splitting off to explore the building. A demon comes out of the furnace in the basement and begins possessing people. At the end of the film, a male and female escape the building and property by scaling a brick wall. They finally make it out just in time to see the sun rise.

Comment: Incredible, that's the one! Thank you for the much-needed closure!